# How to each row in the RecyclerView, use the buttonSheet?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add ButtonSheet for each row in RecyclerView,But i did not succeed.
I still have no solution though. Any information is helpful.

Here is code in adapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Data> dataList;
Context context;
private BottomSheetBehavior behavior;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {...}

public DataAdapter(List<Data> dataList, Context context) {
    this.dataList = dataList;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {...}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Data data = dataList.get(position);

    holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onemain_activity, null);

            final View bottomSheet = vi.findViewById(R.id.dialogBottomSheet);
            behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            behavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            behavior.setPeekHeight(300);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {...}
```

}